How to display nicknames using discord bots?
This is my first time using this website.
I have a question in Discord.py.
let say I want to use a certain command in my bot, like !nickname.
Then the bot displays my nickname on the server. How do I do that?
I tried to execute the message.author, and I got errors.

Hi and welcome to stack overflow, in order to help you, please edit your question with what you got so far (code of the bot), see this article.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

if you have some code then you should show it in question with full error message.

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

# Make sure your bot has intent to fetch memeber details
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.command(name='nickname')
async def nickname(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    nickname = member.nick if member.nick else member.name
    await ctx.send(f'Your nickname is: {nickname}')

# If you want to handle errors for the command use this method
@nickname.error
async def nickname_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, discord.DiscordException):
        await ctx.send('An error occurred while trying to fetch your nickname.')

bot.run('YOUR_BOT_TOKEN')


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
